# Android component build failed by URI has an authority component

Tags: java, android

When I merge an app and then run make command by
`./mk -t se02 mm packages/apps/Remote` (this command just the same as mmm packages/apps/Remote), it failed and display error log as below:

```
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE se02
target Java: Remote (out/target/common/obj/APPS/Remote_intermediates/classes)
warning: com/activeandroid/query/Select.class(com/activeandroid/query:Select.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
warning: com/songshu/gallery/SSPushManager.class(com/songshu/gallery:SSPushManager.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
warning: com/songshu/gallery/SSPushReceiver.class(com/songshu/gallery:SSPushReceiver.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
error: Exception thrown while constructing Processor object: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
make[1]:  [out/target/common/obj/APPS/Remote_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar] Error 41
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/leo/source/temp/Mtk'
                         out/target/product/se02_mm.log_err
                    ==> [FAIL]  2015/11/17 15:45:24
make:  [mm] Error 1
```

The Android env is MTK android 4.2.2, jdk version is 1.6; anyone knows what caused this issue? is it an env settings issue? or code issue? Thanks in advance!